# Integrating Jenkins CI/CD with WinDev Framework for Academic Project

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins-pipeline, devops, computer-science, windev

I'm working on an academic project developed using WinDev, an older framework. I'm looking to implement a CI/CD pipeline with Jenkins for this project. However, I'm facing challenges finding resources or tutorials on integrating Jenkins and unit testing with WinDev. Is it feasible to integrate Jenkins with WinDev for CI/CD purposes? If so, what steps or resources can I follow to achieve this integration? Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.